# How can I scale up actions?

Tags: animation

I wanted to know if it's possible to scale up an action globally if that makes any sense. I have a rigged character which needed to be scaled up by 100 (so that the rig worked properly in a game engine) but that messed up the actions I had animated. Is there a way to add the same scale value to the action so that all the IKs match up?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I found a way to do it. You need to scale the mesh and then apply the scale. But that doesn't work perfectly for me though. For some reason my mesh moves up after applying the scale.

Comment: To scale an animation, you need to multiply the location keyframes while leaving rotation and scale frames untouched.  Use "loc" as a text filter in the graph editor to show only location keyframes, set the cursor to location 0,0, then select all keyframe registrations and s y 10 enter to scale the animation up ten-fold, for example.

Comment: You can't scale actions, you'd need to put them back on the rig, scale up and export. You could probably make a python script to automate this, but the easier way is probably to just add the scaling in the game engine on a parent entity so that the model interprets the animations as is.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you did not scale both the armature and the mesh together, but without the malfunctioning .blend file I could be way off-base.

Comment: How this is a answer?

Comment: They are scaled up properly. I even scaled them up the same amount individually and re-skinned the mesh. It's the action that doesnt scale up.